# Request.IsLocal inside a class library (mvc3, vs2010)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, request

Little stuck, i need to use Request.IsLocal inside a class library, not the web project. How should i be dong this?

System.Web and System.Web.Mvc are referenced in there.

Comment: I would use the Request value as a parameter in a method and check if it the request is local? Its very hard to give an answer with this little information? Where do you want to check if the request is local?

Comment: Or you can write an extension method for a HtmlHelper and get the Request from the HtmlHelper.

Comment: This is a common method that i am utilizing for my navigation. Basically, currently this site is setup as an appication inside another application. So path starts with "/NetSite". In future this will replace the original app and "/NetSite" will be go away. At this point, I need to tag along "/NetSite" with my (part of) URL where ever i need to use String.StartsWith. "Contains" does not work for me this specific occurance. Or i guess i am making it way over complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var isLocal = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal;
```

No, I am kidding. Promise me you will never do anything like that. You shouldn't need something like this in a class library. Or if you need it, you should pass this information to the class library as, for example, method argument from the UI layer which has the notion of Request. Otherwise you will tying your class library to ASP.NET and an HttpContext making it non-reusable.

Comment: Thanks for you input really apreciate it, this class library will never ever be used in another projct. This is very specific to this application. Most common functionality is in a separate project.

Comment: @learning..., it doesn't matter, it's still very bad design. It makes your class library tied to an HttpContext. It makes your class library impossible to unit test. Please, promise me to never commit a crime by writing such code.